# FatalThrowableError Call to a member function setCookie() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, condiciones

Realmente no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, resulta que tengo dos middleware uno que redirecciona a usuarios a completar su registro y el otro que evita que accedan a la ruta si ya lo hicieron por seguridad.

En la base de datos se inserta una columna nueva con un 0 en el campo "wizard" si estos no completaron su registro y si lo hicieron se pone 1, junto a su id de usuario, tambien si no hay registros de ese usuario redirecciona a crearlos, va bien pero algo estoy haciendo mal en los middleware que al usuario que se acaba de registrar y nunca ha creado un registro lo redirecciona al inicio (/dashboard) y aparece el error `Call to a member function setCookie() on null`, pero la logica va bien porque si el usuario completo su registro y yo(por x razon desde mi panel le inserto un 0 al campo wizard del usuario lo devuelve nuevamente a crear su registro) entonces en resumen estoy mal pero no veo en donde :C

Dejare todos mis archivos y espero alguien pueda ayudarme a encontrar el error
Cabe mencionar que modifique el redireccionamiento despues de iniciar sesion y de registrarse ambos envian a la ruta /dashboard

Este es mi archivo de rutas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['lang']], function () {
        Route::get('lang/{lang}', function ($lang) {
           session(['lang' => $lang]);
           return \Redirect::back();
         })->where([
            'lang' => 'en|es|pt-BR'
            ]);
        Auth::routes();
        Route::get('/wizard', ['as' => 'denied', function() {
            return redirect('home')->with('status', 'No tienes permiso de ingresar a esta ruta porque ya configuraste tu empresa');
            }])->name('wizard')->middleware('wizard');
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['wizard']], function () {
            // Rutas protegidas por el middleware
            Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
            Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
            Route::resource('empresas', 'EmpresasController');
        });
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        });
        Route::resource('empresas', 'EmpresasController');
});
```

este es el middleware denied.php:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
    use App\Empresa;

    class Denied
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
            if($data->wizard === null) {
                  return view('admin.wizard');
              }
            if($data->wizard === 1) {
                  return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'No tienes permiso de ingresar a esta ruta porque ya configuraste tu empresa');
              }
            if($data->wizard === 0) {
                return view('admin.wizard');
              }
              return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Este es el middleware WizardVerification.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Closure;
use App\Empresa;

class WizardVerification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
          $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
          if($data === null) {
              return view('admin.wizard');
          }
          if($data->wizard == 0){
             return redirect()->route('deniedwizard');
          }
          if($data->wizard == 1){
             return $next($request);
          }


}}
```

El Controlador DashboardController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

y el HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use App\Empresa;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     public function index()
    {
      return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo esta es la clase Empresa.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empresa extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'empresas';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['nombreempresa',
    'nombrecomercial',
    'idfiscal',
    'logo',
    'adminid',
    'tel',
    'pais',
    'status',
    'email',
    'acceso',
    'verified',
    'categoria',
    'sector',
    'tipo',
    'serial',
    'wizard',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'];
    public function user()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
}
```